# Use data matrix as a fiducial to obtain angle of rotation

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, image-thresholding, datamatrix

[image]

I have a bunch of images such as the one above. They each contain a data matrix, but do not guarantee that it is oriented to an axis. Nevertheless, I can read these matrices with `libdmtx` pretty reliably regardless of their rotation. However, I also need to rotate the image so that the label is oriented right-side-up. My thought process is that I need to get the angle of rotation of the data matrix so that I can rotate the image with PIL to orient it correctly. `pylibdmtx.decode` returns the data that the matrix contains, as well as a rectangle which I originally thought was the bounding box of the data matrix. To test this, I ran the following code with the image above:

```py
from PIL import Image
from pylibdmtx.pylibdmtx import decode

def segment_qr_code(image: Image.Image):
    data = decode(image)[0]
    print(data.rect)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    segment_qr_code(Image.open('<path to image>'))
```

Unfortunately, this code returned `Rect(left=208, top=112, width=94, height=-9)`. Because the height is negative, I don't think it is the bounding box to the data matrix, and if it is, I don't know how to use it to get the angle of rotation.

My question is, **what is the best way to obtain the angle of rotation of the data matrix?** I originally thought that I could crop the image with the bounding box to get a segmented image of *just* the data matrix. Then I could use image thresholding or contouring to get an angle of rotation. However, I'm not sure how to get the correct bounding box, and even if I did I don't know how to use thresholding. I would also prefer to not use thresholding because it isn't always accurate. The data matrix always has a solid border on the bottom and left sides, so I think it may be possible to use it as a fiducial to align the image, however I was unable to find any libraries that were able to return the angle of rotation of the data matrix.

I am open to any suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Threshold on white. Then get contours. The use cv2.minAreaRect() to get the angle of the quadrilateral.

Comment: Have you seen [this issue](https://github.com/NaturalHistoryMuseum/pylibdmtx/issues/51)? Seems like they've offered some workarounds.

Comment: Seems like theyre slow to incorporate a fix. A PR was submitted to try and fix this close to a year ago https://github.com/NaturalHistoryMuseum/pylibdmtx/pull/85

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you to @flakes for the suggestion. Combining code from the PR and issue, I created the following solution:

```py
from pylibdmtx.pylibdmtx import _region, _decoder, _image, _pixel_data, _decoded_matrix_region
from pylibdmtx.wrapper import c_ubyte_p, DmtxPackOrder, DmtxVector2, dmtxMatrix3VMultiplyBy, DmtxUndefined
from ctypes import cast, string_at
from collections import namedtuple
import numpy

_pack_order = {
    8: DmtxPackOrder.DmtxPack8bppK,
    16: DmtxPackOrder.DmtxPack16bppRGB,
    24: DmtxPackOrder.DmtxPack24bppRGB,
    32: DmtxPackOrder.DmtxPack32bppRGBX,
}
Decoded = namedtuple('Decoded', 'data rect')


def decode_with_region(image):
    results = []
    pixels, width, height, bpp = _pixel_data(image)
    with _image(cast(pixels, c_ubyte_p), width, height, _pack_order[bpp]) as img:
        with _decoder(img, 1) as decoder:
            while True:
                with _region(decoder, None) as region:
                    if not region:
                        break
                    else:
                        res = _decode_region(decoder, region)
                        if res:
                            open_cv_image = numpy.array(image)
                            # Convert RGB to BGR
                            open_cv_image = open_cv_image[:, :, ::-1].copy()
                            height, width, _ = open_cv_image.shape

                            topLeft = (res.rect['01']['x'], height - res.rect['01']['y'])
                            topRight = (res.rect['11']['x'], height - res.rect['11']['y'])
                            bottomRight = (res.rect['10']['x'], height - res.rect['10']['y'])
                            bottomLeft = (res.rect['00']['x'], height - res.rect['00']['y'])
                            results.append(Decoded(res.data, (topLeft, topRight, bottomRight, bottomLeft)))
    return results


def _decode_region(decoder, region):
    with _decoded_matrix_region(decoder, region, DmtxUndefined) as msg:
        if msg:
            vector00 = DmtxVector2()
            vector11 = DmtxVector2(1.0, 1.0)
            vector10 = DmtxVector2(1.0, 0.0)
            vector01 = DmtxVector2(0.0, 1.0)
            dmtxMatrix3VMultiplyBy(vector00, region.contents.fit2raw)
            dmtxMatrix3VMultiplyBy(vector11, region.contents.fit2raw)
            dmtxMatrix3VMultiplyBy(vector01, region.contents.fit2raw)
            dmtxMatrix3VMultiplyBy(vector10, region.contents.fit2raw)

            return Decoded(
                string_at(msg.contents.output),
                {
                    '00': {
                        'x': int((vector00.X) + 0.5),
                        'y': int((vector00.Y) + 0.5)
                    },
                    '01': {
                        'x': int((vector01.X) + 0.5),
                        'y': int((vector01.Y) + 0.5)
                    },
                    '10': {
                        'x': int((vector10.X) + 0.5),
                        'y': int((vector10.Y) + 0.5)
                    },
                    '11': {
                        'x': int((vector11.X) + 0.5),
                        'y': int((vector11.Y) + 0.5)
                    }
                }
            )
        else:
            return None
```

To decode an image, use `decode_with_region()` instead of pylibdmtx's `decode()`. It outputs a dictionary of coordinates, which I can plot on an image and get the following output:

[image]

I can then use these coordinates to obtain an angle of rotation:

```py
def get_data_from_matrix(image):
    decoded = decode_with_region(image)[0]
    topLeft, topRight = decoded.rect[2], decoded.rect[3]
    rotation = -math.atan2(topLeft[1] - topRight[1], topLeft[0] - topRight[0]) * (180 / math.pi)
    image = image.rotate(rotation, expand=True)
```

Comment: Nice, glad to have helped! Always worth doing a search in the upstream project when digging into usage issues like this. Might be worth adding a link to this post on the Github issue for anyone else struggling with this problem!